# read.xlsx2 | Skipping if sheetName does not exist

Tags: r, r-xlsx

I am trying to read multiple excel files in a folder using the read.xlsx2 function. I only need to read a particular sheet titled 'Returns' or 'Prices'.

Is there a way I can give an 'OR' argument in the function and also skip a file if it contains neither of the sheets?

P.s.: Each file will have either a 'Returns' or a 'Prices' sheet or neither but not both so there cannot be a clash.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read all the sheet names of the file and using `intersect` select one of `'Returns'` or `'Prices'` whichever is present in the sheet and read the excel file with that sheet.

Using `readxl` you can do this as :

```
library(readxl)

all_files <- list.files(pattern = '\\.xlsx$')

result <- lapply(all_files, function(x) {
  all_sheets <- excel_sheets(x)  
  correct_sheet <- intersect(all_sheets, c('Returns', 'Prices'))
  if(length(correct_sheet)) read_xlsx(x, correct_sheet)
})
```

`result` will have a list of dataframes. If you want to combine the data into one dataframe and if they have same column names you can use `do.call(rbind, result)`